# Cannot uninstall my tool after adding entry to the 'Uninstall' registry key

Tags: c++, windows, registry, uninstallation

I'm developing a simple win32 tool. I'd the tool to be easily uninstalled by the user so I've added a subkey to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

called `MyTool` and added all the necessary keys such as: `DisplayName`,`UninstallString`,`DisplayVersion`,`DisplayIcon`

So far so good. I can see that during the install process of my tool, the new subkey was added and everything is as expected.

#### Problem

When I come to uninstall my tool and press uninstall I get the following error:

```
You do not have sufficient access to uninstall MyTool. Please contact your system administrator
```

#### Notes

My process is 32 bit. However, `Wow6432Node` related topic is irrelevant since I've encounter this issue both in 32 & 64 bit systems.

#### Question

Did I do something wrong with the way I've added the registry subkey?

Comment: It may be the fact you are using registers? Is there any other way you know to uninstall the tool? Is there a purpose of having it? Why can't make the user just go to the control panel and uninstall from there?

Comment: @Auriga. I don't follow you.. In order for the user to have an uninstall entry in the control panel, I, as the tool developer, need to add a proper entry in the registry. This is what I did.

Comment: I don't see how we could diagnose whether there's something wrong with how you added the registry subkey, without knowing how you added the registry subkey...

Comment: @Auriga: This is _how_ to add an entry to that Control Panel area.

Comment: Just like installing the application, uninstalling the tool requires administrator privileges. If you have reason to believe, that uninstalling your tool should not require administrator privileges, please explain why. Otherwise, the observed behavior is the expected behavior.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand I did not provide much information. But perhaps someone could shade some light despite of that (for example, Had I forgotten to add the key `UninstallString`, you could have immediately notice something is wrong)

Comment: @IInspectable I know very little about this, but I would expect the Uninstall panel to launch UAC if admin privs aren't already present. Same way the user could install the program in the first place.

Comment: @Lightness: The shell doesn't launch the UAC prompt automagically. It has to be told to, either by specifying the appropriate verb in a call to `ShellExecuteEx`, or by providing the *runas* value of the respective entry in a manifest. Since we don't know whether the uninstaller is the same module as the installer, there's not much to expect other than guesswork.

Comment: @IInspectable: Okay so the Control Panel doesn't automatically give/request admin privs for an uninstaller? The uninstaller itself has to request it? That sounds like the basis for an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the kind of time-wasting bugs that are so stupid.

The issue was, believe it or not, the **path separator** used in key's value: `UninstallString`.

#### Generating error

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/MyTool/my_tool.exe" /uninstall"
```

#### Working

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyTool\my_tool.exe" /uninstall
```

Regardless of whether or not it is my fault as a developer, why would windows error out in this case?